# Rendering array from Axios server on reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a server with json data.

I get the data to my app

```
  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/persons').then(response => {
  const contacts = response.data
  console.log(contacts)
```

I can log the response data, so the data is there, stored in the contacts variable.

[image]

So, I want to display the contacts array data.

I tried this inside return:

```
<ul>
      {contacts.map(contact => 
     
          <Contact key={contact.id} contact={contact.name}  />
         
        )}
      </ul>
```

But I get this error:

> src\App.js
> Line 116:8:   'contacts' is not defined  no-undef
> Line 118:12:  'Contact' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

How contacts is not defined? const contacts is right below App.

Full code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Person from './components/Person'
import Form from './components/Form'
import Filter from './components/Filter'
import axios from 'axios'
import FilterResults from './components/FilterResults'
import contactService from './services/persons'


const App = () => {

  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/persons').then(response => {
  const contacts = response.data
  console.log(contacts)
    
  
})
  
/*   contactService
  .getAll()
  .then(response => {
    setPersons(response.data)
  }) */

/*   const promise = axios.get('http://localhost:3001/persons')
  console.log(promise) */

  //Reminder: current state, function that updates it, initial state.
  const [ persons, setPersons ] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '040-123456' },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523' },
    { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345' },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122' }
  ]) 
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')
  const [ newNumber, setNewNumber ] = useState('')
  //Filter
  const [ filter, setFilter ] = useState('')
  
  //adding new persons
  const addPerson = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    /* complete the addPerson function for creating new persons */
    const personObject = {
      name: newName,
      number: newNumber,
      //The server will create the id 
      //id: persons.length + 1,
    }
//TODO: Get data from the server and not harcoded
    //Adding the data to the server
    /* 
    using separate server comunication module from persons.js
     "create" instead of previous code:
    axios
    .post('http://localhost:3001/persons', personObject) 
    
    replaced by:
    
    contactService
    .create(personObject)
    */

  

   


    contactService
    .create(personObject)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
         //After concat, the fiel is set to blank again ('').

    setPersons(persons.concat(personObject))
    setNewName('')
    setNewNumber('')
    })

  
  }
 

  const handlePersonChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setNewName(event.target.value)
  }
  const handleNumberChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setNewNumber(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setFilter(event.target.value)
  }
  const personsToShow = filter === ''
    ? persons
    : persons.filter(person =>
        person.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()))
  const row_names = () => personsToShow.map(person => 
    <p key={person.name}>{person.name} {person.number}</p>
  )


  return (
    <div>
 <Filter value={filter} onChange={handleFilterChange} />

      <Form
      onSubmit={addPerson}
      name={{value: newName, onChange: handlePersonChange}}
      number={{value: newNumber, onChange: handleNumberChange}}

      />
{/* <ul>
      {contacts.map(contact => 
     
          <Contact key={contact.id} contact={contact.name}  />
         
        )}
      </ul> */}
      
      <h2>Numbers hardcoded</h2>


      

      {console.log(persons)}
      {/* <ul>
      {persons.map(person => 
      //Pass all the props from person to Person.js
          <Person key={person.id} person={person}  />
         
        )}
      </ul> */}
      <h2>Filter results</h2>
      <FilterResults persons={row_names()} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate on the answer above:

- `'contacts' is not defined`: As the error message states, `contacts` is indeed not defined **on the scope where you're trying to use it**. You're using `const`, which locally scopes your variable. It means that outside of its scope, it will be undefined:

```js
axios.get('http://localhost:3001/persons').then(response => {
  // This function is the scope of the response variable
  // It means you cannot access it anywhere else
})
```

To understand more this concept, you can read You-Dont-Know-JS, more specifically "[Scoping with Blocks](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch6.md#scoping-with-blocks)".

- `'Contact' is not defined`: You forgot to import your `<Contact />` component. I've just read in your comment that you have no `<Contact />` component, so this won't work. Read React's [Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) section of the docs. You're probably expecting some magic in that React would magically create a component named like this for you. There's no magic, React is not a framework, it's a library: it's "just JS(X)".

As it was implied in the answer above, making that `axios.get()` call directly in the "root" of your component is not a good idea. It would get called at every render. Not only that, but you're going to have a hard time using the `contacts` variable.
You could use the async/await syntax to solve the variable access issue:

```js
const App = async (props) => {
  const contactsResponse = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/persons");

  return contactsResponse.data.map((contact) => (
    <Contact key={contact.id} contact={contact.name} />
  ));
};
```

That will "solve" the variable access issue, and you will then notice the next problem. To then fix this issue with fetching from the "root' of your components, and to understand why you would never want this, make sure you have a good understanding on a component's [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). When that's done, have a look at React docs for [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), namely [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). They're what you're looking for here.

Answer (score -1):

For the `Line 116:8: 'contacts' is not defined no-undef` error :

You should add `const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([])` and replace `const contacts = response.data` by `setContacts(response.data)`

For the `Line 118:12: 'Contact' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef` error :

I don't see where you import the `Contact` component

Comment: That "solves" it (at least for the undefined parts) while not explaining what's wrong and providing extra steps with no value. You should explain why the need for extracting the variable to state. In this particular case, that won't improve anything, the XHR will still get fired at every rerender.

Comment: It makes an infinite loop of get requests. 
VersifiXion, I am not using a Contact component. By now I just wanted to render the array. I guess it was a wrong aproach.

Comment: using useEffect solved the infinite loop issue